# How to install vinecopulib library for C++ on Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am new to C++ and I am having a hard time installing the vinecopulib on Xcode, available at https://github.com/vinecopulib/vinecopulib. The instructions given are quite technical and little is given about how to do it on a Mac.

What I really need is to work with Gaussian Bivariate Copula (and eventually other copulas).

How to get the library set up and working?

P.S: Is there an easy way load packages/libraries on Xcode/C++? on R, it's fairly straightforward, just doing install.packages(...)

Comment: They have [detailed instructions](https://github.com/vinecopulib/vinecopulib#getting-started) how to use that library. Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: *"If you just want to use vinecopulib, you can use the header files (located in the `includes` folder) right away."* - sounds pretty simple, what trouble are you having with this?

Comment: They do have the instructions, but I don't understand them. I am new to XCode and looked at some online tutorials of how to load a library on XCode (and they talk about search header paths etc not found in the instructions given)  I am still stuck on the very starting point of loading the library on Xcode.

Comment: I believe there is a whole set of header files linked to each other and I want to have them all on XCode. I tried the #include "vinecopulib.hpp" and included that header file in my project, but all I got is "File not found"

Comment: @Newbie If you're new to all this, you should probably start out with something simpler, until you have learned enough about the basics.

Comment: @Newbie _"The instructions given are quite technical ..."_ Sure they are and should be. I don't think there's so much specific for Mac, that code looks like portable stuff for various OS.

Comment: I understand that. But what I wanted was a step- by- step guide as to how to proceed. There's no resources online that would enable a person with limited knowledge in coding to be able to follow the instructions given to build that library. I am aware the question is not specific, because i don't even know the starting point. An easy- to- follow step- by- step guide would be actually very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Vinecopulib is header-only. It means that you use the CMake build system, but only to build the documentation and unit-tests, and to automate installation (i.e., place headers in the usual location). If you just want to use vinecopulib, you can use the header files (located in theincludesfolder) right away.

We provide an option to precompile compiled the library in order to save building time (and memory) via the CMake option VINECOPULIB_SHARED_LIB. Source files are generated from header files and the CMake build system additionally allows to install the .dylib/.so/.dll object.

Comment: Ask me if you need any help

Comment: Comment on this answer if you need a different answer

Comment: Thank you @Ibraheem Ali! I have managed with some help to build the library, and include it in my project. I can use #include "vinecopulib.hpp" without it being highlighted (So, that's good I suppose). But now, when I run the code, it says "Build Succeeded"  but there is an internal error, saying - could not launch "Project 1"

Comment: it says: error: executable doesn't exist: '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_1-fhyoxhrxasepsjawxsbftlkfouai/Build/Products/Debug/Project 1'
error: failed to launch '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_1-fhyoxhrxasepsjawxsbftlkfouai/Build/Products/Debug/Project 1' -- internal error... Do you have any idea what this could be related to and how I can tackle it?

Comment: I don't know of this will help but try to do:

Comment: Product -> Clean

Comment: See if that helps

Comment: Nope. I still have the same error

Comment: what type is your Xcode

Comment: Try updating the OS to mojave

Comment: If it already isn't

Comment: Do you mean the version?

Comment: Yes. Is it High Sierra or Mojave?

Comment: it's high Sierra. I cannot update to Mojave because there's not enough space

Comment: what about the Xcode

Comment: Why don't you try to upgrade your storage and then try

Comment: It's version 10.1.... The thing is when I downloaded some of the dependencies required ( like boost or eigen I think), I downloaded the High Sierra version. I don't know if that will be problematic

Comment: good. That means it will be easier than let's say 9.1 or 8.2

Comment: maybe you could try update the Xcode and try to run it then but in the meanwhile I will try and figure out how to fix it

Comment: I keep on getting an error even without the libraries with every project I do. It is "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". I have no idea how to fix it and I think you should try find the library code and repasting it in to the code

Comment: You could try to debug of course

Comment: It could also be one of those glitchy unnecessary errors. I used to get them all the time